# "Springing leaks" and "springing gas"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, singular-vs-plural

From the movie *Moon*: ([YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/xPLhpLfCFaE?t=20))

> Gerty: There is no damage to the exterior shell.
>
> Sam: Well, it's not that I don't believe you, Gerty, but I mean, you know, this thing is **springing leaks** like an Acme fire hose. You need to let me go outside and fix this problem, Gerty.
>
> Gerty: I can't let you go outside, Sam.
>
> Sam: Gerty, if you don't let me go outside, we can't fix this leak.
>
> Gerty: I'm not permitted to let you go outside.
>
> Sam: Just let... We'll keep it between you and me. Okay, pal? This thing is **springing gas**, let's go. Come on.

The phrases "springing leaks", "springing gas" strike me as strange. I understand "springing gas" means "emitting gas", but as far as I have checked the dictionaries (OED, M-W, Lexico, etc.), "spring" doesn't have the meaning of "give off" or "emit". I thought it could be "spewing gas", but the audio and subtitles both point to "springing gas".

Also if "spring" means *spew*, *emit* in "springing gas", it wouldn't make much sense in "springing leaks". What does "spring" mean here? Also why is *leak* in the plural? A [leak](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/leak) is a hole or an instance of leaking. There is only one instance of leaking as a resulting of one hole, so why "springing leaks"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "spring a leak" is a phrase meaning to begin to let liquid pass through a crack or hole in a boat or vessel. Its use in connection with leaks of air or gas is slightly non-standard, but not so much that it is incorrect.

> spring a leak
>
> if a boat or a container springs a leak, it begins to let liquid in or
>   out through a crack or hole.

[Spring a leak](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/spring-a-leak)